# Clear asynchronous calls on hooks -React Native/Firebase how I do?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native

I'm trying to clear a call I make to find out if my user is logged in. it is important to remember the onAuthStateChanged listener is asynchronous and will trigger an initial state once a connection with Firebase has been established

The problem is when I try to make a new call, the message just appears in the log that I have to cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in usseEffect, What should I do?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text,StyleSheet, Alert,TouchableOpacity, ActivityIndicator, Image } from 
'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';
import {
GoogleSignin,
GoogleSigninButton,
statusCodes,
} from '@react-native-community/google-signin';

GoogleSignin.configure()

  export default function BoasVindas({navigation})
    {
      // Set an initializing state whilst Firebase connects
      const [initializing, setInitializing] = useState(true);
      const [user, setUser] = useState();
      const [logado, setlogado] = useState(false);


      // Handle user state changes
     console.log("Usuario =:",user);
    function onAuthStateChanged(user) {
     setUser(user);
     if (initializing) setInitializing(false);
 
   }

function SignOut()
  {
  
      auth()
      .signOut()
      .then(() => {
          Alert.alert('Deslogado');
      })
      setInitializing(true)

      // if(user)
      // {
      //   await GoogleSignin.revokeAccess();
      //   await GoogleSignin.signOut();
      //   setUser(null);
       
      // }

     
        navigation.navigate('Acess');
  

   }

   useEffect(() => {
 const subscriber = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
 
  return () => {subscriber} ;
 }, []);

 if (initializing) return null;

 if(!user)
 { 
  return(
 <View style={{flex: 1,justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 
 '#191919'}}>
    <ActivityIndicator size="large" color="#9E9E9E"/>
   </View>
   );

  }



  return (
 <View style={styles.container}>
   <View style={styles.viewUser}>
      <Text style={styles.boasvindas}>Boas vindas </Text>
      <Image
    style={styles.tinyLogo}
    source={{
      uri: user.photoURL,
    }}
  />
      <Text style={styles.nameUser}>{user.displayName}</Text>
   </View>

   <TouchableOpacity style={styles.SignOut}
   onPress={ SignOut}>
       <Text style={styles.sair}> Sign Out</Text>
   </TouchableOpacity>
 </View>
    );


  

   }
 const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
  backgroundColor: '#1C1C1C',
  flex: 1,

  
},
boasvindas: {
  fontFamily: 'BebasNeue-Regular',
  color: 'white',
  fontSize: 40,
},
viewUser: {
  marginTop: 20,
  alignItems: 'center',

},
tinyLogo: {
  width: 50,
  height: 50,
  borderRadius: 100,
},
nameUser: {
  marginTop: 10,
  fontSize: 20,
  fontFamily: 'CaviarDreams',
  color: 'white',
},
SignOut: {
  top: 350,
  backgroundColor: '#e67e22',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  width: 120,
  marginLeft: 30,
  borderRadius: 17,
},
sair: {
  fontFamily: 'CaviarDreams_Bold',
    
  padding:12,
}
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`onAuthStateChanged` returns an unsubscribe function. You will just need to return this function from your effect, and react will call it when the component unmounts. You seem to be thinking along those lines already, but don't have it quite right yet. Try this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  const unsubscribe = auth().onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

Or without the intermediate variable:

```
useEffect(() => {
  return auth.onAuthStateChanged(onAuthStateChanged);
}, []);
```

Comment: I had already done this, and it really worked, the fact that I persisted in the problem is that I didn't understand why the way I posted the return function it didn't work.